# Paginated report- export to pdf for all individual filter values separately

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

Is there really a way to export Power BI reports for each filter value separately in a PDF/PowerPoint file?

Some users have asked this question before on Power BI community forums ([this](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Print-to-PDF-how-to-automate-for-each-filter-value/td-p/486753) and [this](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Print-page-to-separate-PDF-for-each-value-of-a-filter/td-p/748417)) and the accepted solution is to use a Paginated report. But I'm not able to figure out how to do this with a Paginated report.

And can this be also done with reports created with Power BI Desktop Pro version?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are definitely referring to PBI Report server (as tagged), you would be looking to setup subscriptions on the paginated report.
Each subscription can have a different value for the parameters/filters.

You can setup each subscription to save to a (network) drive, or send to an email etc and you setup your file type (pdf, excel, etc)

Another thing to maybe consider, if you have grouped your data in the report, so even if you have 5 things in your filter all selected, you could use the page break option in your group. This means when you save it to PDF each group will be on it's own page.